# System.Windows.Forms.Timer does not exist

Tags: c#, timer, using-directives

I am trying to set up a timer in c#. In "using" part I have included this

```
using System.Windows.Forms.Timer;
```

My timer looks like this:

```
private Timer timer1;
public void InitTimer()
{
     timer1 = new Timer();
     timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
     timer1.Interval = 1000; 
     timer1.Start();
}
```

However "Timer" is underlined, and I am getting this error:

> "The type namespace 'Timer' could not be found(are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)"

I thought, that this will be included by default. If not, what do I need to include as a reference?

Thank you.

Comment: can you check whether you have reference to system.windows.forms.dll

Answer (score 2):

The namespace should be:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

`Timer` is a class within that namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference to the System.Windows.Forms DLL, if it is not a Windows Form Application. And if it is, please post a full snippet if possible.

Another option is to use the System.Threading.Timers namespace.

Comment: Yes, I can see System.Windows.Forms in my references

Comment: sorry missed it.. as Eren mentions, you don't need the .Timer in the namespace declaration.